# Make text cursor position above soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a some multiline EditText controls in a ScrollView.
When I tap any of the EditText controls, the soft keyboard appears,

but the EditText and its cursor position appears behind the keyboard. 
I need to manually scroll the view to top.

I tried scrolling the scrollView to bottom on EditText Click, But this won't work as the keyboard appears after the EditText onClick, and layout resized as keyboard appears.

Is there any way to fix this issue? 
In the below code cameraButton always appear above the keyboard.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/crlayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/boxImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_box_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_box_descri"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="Open Camera"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_box_camera_icon"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you tried this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` add to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes... I am using this to keep my camera button above keyboard.
But here issue is inside scrollview. I want scrollview to be scrolled down when user focuses on EditText control

Comment: found any solution for this?